# Sending signal from mic preamp to guitar pedal effect

Tags: recording, homerecording, production

I'm planning to use a fuzz effect from my guitar pedal on my vocals. Therefore I plan to send signal through my microphone to mic preamp and then to the Behringer sf300 super fuzz pedal. From there it will go to my audio interface.

I'd also like to do some reamping but without an actual reamp, but by sending my signal straight from my audio interface line out to this pedal and then again to the audio interface.

Will it all work? How about impedance from preamp/audio interface output and pedals input (it's 500k ohms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the balanced line signal (mic pre) to instrument level (effect pedal) and then from the effect pedal back to line level (your audio interface). See the example from the [manual](https://www.radialeng.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/manual-xamp.pdf) here on page 7

Comment: Is signal from mic preamp too weak for effect pedal? I read that it works fine for some people, without reamp device. I'll buy it if I have to but if I could save some money it would be great.